# Check if a file is opened by another process

Tags: files, process, freebsd

Is there a way to check if a file with given name is opened by some process (other than our process)?

I need this on FreeBSD. It would be nice to also support Linux. I write in Perl.

Techniques requiring root access are not suitable.

Comment: Could you simply be looking for the `fuser` command?

Comment: ... or quite possibly `lsof`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Can it be done in Perl, without calling a shell command? (Or is `fuser` more portable?)

Comment: Google `fuser in perl` gives me http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/Linux-Fuser-1.5/lib/Linux/Fuser.pm as the first result.

Comment: There isn't, AFAIK, a standard system call to find this info—so you need some native, per-OS code to do it. One of the shell commands is probably the most portable way to get that native code, unless you find something on CPAN.

Comment: @JuliePelletier that module claims to be Linux only.

Comment: Since you're supposedly a Perl developer, then I would assume you know how to write Perl code and conditions to apply rules for each OS since a good solution like using system built-in commands like `fuser` are not good enough for your skill level!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`fstat`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?fstat) command, you can run it as `user` :

> The `fstat` utility identifies open files.  A file is considered open by a
>    process if it was explicitly opened, is the working directory, root
>    directory, jail root directory, active executable text, or kernel trace
>    file for that process.  If no options are specified, fstat reports on all open files in the system.

Comment: +1 Note that the fstat utility is specific to BSD and not related to the Linux stat/fstat system calls. In Linux there is only lsof.